# Visual Studio 2010 Deployment Security Cerftificates

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, certificate

Does anyone know if it is possible to include a .cer and .pfx file in a visual studio 2010 setup project?

Answer (score -1):

The answer for me was to use Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset